Build a CMS using nodejs and express with socketio for realtime updates without clientside refresh
I am starting a project to build a basic cms using nodejs and I want to use websockets as well. I don't know where to find resources to learn how best to do this.
I want a site I can post things to sort of like drupal: allowing me to create and view things in a database based on custom content types and fields of those content types which are also of custom content types. But I want to be able incorporate custom games with something like the old battle.net chat system with rooms and games you can search and join - which I imagine are also sort of like rooms.
I've experimented with socket.io in the past. I'm okay with nodejs and express. But whenever I try to find resources about building something with socket.io or websockets, it seems to only be rudimentary chat applications. I would like to send html, css and js files with websockets/socketio and not just messages with data - I want to send files.
I don't know where to find something that shows me how to integrate a node/express project sending files with something like socketio sending messages and data objects. Could anyone point me to some resources?
Thank you.
What I tried: I just did a basic search and I tried looking at the top video results from a search of youtube. Socketio documentation didn't seem to help me with anything more than mere chat applications.
